# Email not send after template is changed - content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Not sure what went wrong. Everything as working fine and emails were getting sent. But after making a small change on the footer of our email template, I refreshed the Email content in the content Builder and that blew it.

Whenever I send a test email now it shows in Tracking -> Status: Complete, Emails Sent: 0 for that particular sent. Also I do not receive the test. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any Ampscript in the footer? This can cause sends to fail even if they pass the preview stage

Comment: Have you checked your TEXT version of the email, eyeball it if you see anything off. If there's an issue in either version, your email will not go out. And it validates fine, because only the HTML is validated against (assuming that's good).

Comment: No, it was only a word change that I made. The Amprscript on the template was not touched at all.

Comment: Is the person you are previewing the test send unsubscribed?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but no he is not unsubscribed. I have reached out to Salesforce Support. Will update here if the issue gets resolved.